# appening recursive command for a Linux STDIN

Tags: linux, unix

When moving / copying contents from one folder to another. I get asked if I want to overwrite files sharing identical names. As in this example:

```
[root@public/]# sudo mv * /var/www/public/html/
```

For example, if `public` has 100 files that exist in `html` it will ask if I want to overwrite each file by name 100 time. Is there a way to append the `y` command?

I am a linux newbie. I know we can STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR. I though I could append it doing something like `< "echo y";` but it ain't working.

Comment: You could just use the `-f` flag on `mv`.

Comment: @TimCooper I suppose the `cp` also uses that flag?

Comment: @Simon_eQ instead of asking that question, read the `cp` manpage.

Comment: @slim Doing it now. I only did a basic stuff before.

Comment: @simON ping me in PHP chat, gotta ask you something.

Comment: @crypticツ I can't. You can find me in the [English Language](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage) chat room. I'll be there now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can use the program `yes` for such purposes:

```
yes | mv ...
```

`yes` called without any arguments repeats the string "y" forever but if you pass an argument it will ouput the argument. This leads to the nice call

```
yes no | program
```

which can be used to repeatedly say "no" :)

However, in this case `mv` itself has the option `-f` wich would suppress questions and enforce actions. But I would use it with care as questions are meant to help you prevent data loss.

Comment: I can't get it to work. `mv -f * /var/www/public/domain.com/` is still asking me question.

Comment: I guess this due to an alias in your bashrc. Try `/bin/mv * ...` or use `yes | mv ...` or drop the alias from your bashrc

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems to just be a work around.  You should use `mv -f` to disable the prompt.